# Cannot display hidden div once an option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having problem to show my hidden div once I select either of my options. Currently I have done the javascript code for it.

This is my HTML code:

```
Customer Type:
<select name="customerType">
    <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
    <option value="ret" onClick="custType(this.value)">Customer</option>
    <option value="trd" onClick="custType(this.value)">Trade</option>
</select>
<div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">Company Name
    <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName" />
</div>
```

This is my current Javascript code:

```
function custType(val) {
    if (val == "trd") {
        document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("retCustDetails").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    if (val == "ret") {
        document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("retCustDetails").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

I did some research through stackoverflow and found a solution through the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryxCM/1/) but that code is not working on my file. Can anyone help me out with this. Thank you.

Comment: Code is correct. But i donot see javascript code for selectedIndexChanged event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer for my question. I just had to change the onclick to onchange. It works fine now. Thanks for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onchange event like

```
function custType(val){
    document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails").style.visibility =val == "trd" ? "visible": 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("retCustDetails").style.visibility =val == "ret" ? "visible": 'hidden';
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d4qxr4oo/)

Comment: i think you need to clarify that the onchnage event should be bound to the select, not the options.

Answer (score 0):

Your code DOES work for me. However....I think you forgot to create second div too, or you didn't just include it into your question. I tried this on [onlinehtmleditor](http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/) and it worked just fine. I just created second div with:

```
id=retCustDetails
```